# Python connect to ODBC 2.x database

Tags: python, database, odbc, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to an old database that has its own equally old ODBC driver (which is no longer maintained)

```
# The driver is 32 bit, so I'm using Python 3.8.7 (32bit)
con = pyodbc.connect(r"Driver={CSI RBM 4.02 ODBC Driver};Dbq=" + database_path + ";Server=localhost")
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The driver doesn't support the version of ODBC behavior that the application requested (see SQLSetEnvAttr).
```

According to https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000033360 it means:

```
This error indicates that an application requested ODBC 3.x behavior however the driver was only ODBC 2.x compliant.
```

Which I assume means that Python or Pyodbc is using ODBC 3.x and the driver is using 2.x.

So if I've assumed all that correctly, then my question is **how can I force Pyodbc to use ODBC 2.x, or is there any other way I can connect to this database using Python?**

Any other helpful information would be appreciated too

Comment: Yes, it does appear that pyodbc calls `SQLSetEnvAttr` and specifies `SQL_OV_ODBC3`. If you are on Windows then you could try using ADODB (e.g., via VBScript) to see if you can establish a connection that way.

Comment: Yes I am on windows. Do you think ADODB and VBScript is the only way to do this? Ideally I'd like to keep in Python, but will look into this if need be

Comment: Not necessarily the only way, just a quick way of testing whether something other than pyodbc can work with that driver.

Answer (score 2):

You can build it from source.

In the **/src/pyodbcmodule.cpp** file about at the 330 line change **SQL_OV_ODBC3** to **SQL_OV_ODBC2**  then build and install.
I also have and ancient odbc driver what only works with SQL_OV_ODBC2 but hangs every time with SQL_OV_ODBC3.

**/src/pyodbcmodule.cpp** ~line 330

```
if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC2, sizeof(int) ) ) )
{
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, "Unable to set SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION attribute.");
    return false;
}
```

You can find the source code and documentation for building from sourc here:
https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Building-pyodbc-from-source

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

For driver testing you can use the **ODBC Test** tool from Microsoft.

You can try out any settings of the ODBC driver without writing any code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/odbc-test?view=sql-server-ver15
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21995

[image: ODBC Test]